# How to hide the scroll bar arrows in firefox

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

For Chrome I use -webkit-scrollbar and it automatically removes the up and down arrows but for Firefox I am using scrollbar-color and scrollbar-width styles, but it doesn't get rid of the up and down arrows. Anyone know how to do that?

Also if anyone knows how to add a border radius to the Firefox scroll thumb that would be awesome.

Answer (score 3):

You could use

```
scrollbar-width: thin;
```

Comment: This doesn't provide an answer to question of hiding scroll bar arrows as OP requested.

Comment: Using scrollbar-width: thin hides the arrows.

Comment: I do prefer the scrollbar to be that medium width but I did propose this as a solution and they are going forward with that. Thank you!

Comment: Your answer could use some additional information as in your comment because it is unclear from the code itself.